# How to resolve conflicting directory for CVS?

Tags: version-control, merge, cvs, conflict

How to resolve conflicting directory for CVS?

The situation is that I created some new subdirectories under a CVS working copy:

```
workingCopy/subdir1/
workingCopy/subdir1/file11
workingCopy/subdir2/
workingCopy/subdir2/file2
```

then before i commit these, someone else committed

```
workingCopy/subdir1/
workingCopy/subdir1/file12
workingCopy/subdir2/
```

Now when I try to update, it complains that the directories are conflicting.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can get out of this situation, when you

1. move your own subdir1 out of the way
2. do cvs up
3. move the content of subdir1 into the CVS-subdir1
4. check for differences

Answer (score 0):

In case you may get error sometimes to UPDATE your local version. The final solution is :

> **1. Save your local code to another place manually**
>
> **2. Revert the files/folders which may has conflict to the HEAD (most latest) version on CVS server.**
>
> **3. Add back your change to the Reverted file.**

The concept for above solution is to CLEAR UP all the possible issue by REVERT and get a 100% clean version from repository then add back our changes.

It can resolve below issues which caused by code out of date / code base messed up.

> 1. CVS commit had a conflict and has not been modified
> 2. CVS update failed
> 3. CVS not sync